# Keep css when editing in the browser

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

When I'm experimenting with css (in the dev tools) in the browser, I sometimes need to refresh the page. However, this causes me to lose the changes I've made. Is there a way to prevent this from happening or at least save the state of the last css.

Comment: [First result](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow) in google for "save chrome dev tools changes"

Comment: Thanks @haxxxton, but what if you don't have local access to the files?

Comment: @PatrickMlr, then you're best looking at a tool like [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en), and saving a [script to change the styles](http://www.kossboss.com/web---javascript---tampermonkey---change-css-style-of-certain-pattern---change-the-style-of-all-elements-matching-a-pattern-too) of a site each time you visit it

Comment: @PatrickMlr, nope, that was my bad, tagged you instead of OP by accident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: You **can't** edit temporarily in the dev-tools and reuse it after you reload the site.

You will need an addon to do this. You could use [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) to save it into a fake-implementation.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Frustrating it is indeed. What solved the issue for me is using this tool called [Browser-sync](https://browsersync.io/), this way you can update the css and see the changes at the same time. Give it a go, it's worth it.